# Reading hex string blocks from a file and putting them into an array in java

Tags: java

I want to read the a file where packets are stored as hex files and store them in arrays. For example, the there are three blocks here and I need to store them in 3 separate arrays. The arrays should contain these hex strings. Could someone please advice me the way to do it correctly? I tried using buffered reader and a string buffer but could not implement properly as each block needs to be put in different arrays.

00 04 75 8d 49 c7 00 01 03 cd 50 3c 08 00 45 00
00 30 07 28 40 00 80 06 00 00 c0 a8 ec 20 c0 a8
ec 1e 04 05 00 17 aa a2 9e b3 00 00 00 00 70 02
fa f0 e1 2b 00 00 02 04 05 b4 01 01 04 02

00 01 03 cd 50 3c 00 01 03 dd 4c 2d 08 00 45 00
00 30 00 00 40 00 40 06 e1 37 c0 a8 ec 1e c0 a8
ec 20 00 17 04 05 aa 5a b0 04 aa a2 9e b4 70 12
16 d0 6a dc 00 00 02 04 05 b4 01 01 04 02

00 04 75 8d 49 c7 00 01 03 cd 50 3c 08 00 45 00
00 28 07 29 40 00 80 06 00 00 c0 a8 ec 20 c0 a8
ec 1e 04 05 00 17 aa a2 9e b4 aa 5a b0 05 50 10
fa f0 59 ab 00 00

I have done up to this, but could not get it in the way I want. Especially I want to differentiate each blocks.

```
    BufferedReader br=null;
    try{
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cmd));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
            while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
            {
            sb.append(line);
            }
    String [] store = sb.toString().split(" ");
    pkt = store;
    }catch(IOException ie) {ie.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: please post your attempt that you believe was the closest to working.

Comment: Added, but it is not complete. Thank you.

Comment: it's best to include your code in the question. Click the edit link, skip at least one line from the bottom, and paste your code. Add four spaces at the beginning of each line to make your code look like code on the page.

Comment: Although the code is not doing much, there is a logical error: it glues lines together without spaces, so 40 from the first line's end and 00 from the second's line beginning become 4000.

Answer (score 1):

you need to append a space between your lines for the split to work.

```
sb.append(line).append(' ');
```

You should also use a StringBuilder and not a StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the arrays into a list.

```
    ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
        { 
          if(!"".equals(line.trim())){
                   list.add(line.split(" "));
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to store all your packets in an array list and then process them as you wish at the end of the loop

```
BufferedReader br=null;
ArrayList<String[]> pkts = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 

try{
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cmd));

        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
        {
            pkts.add(line.trim().toString().split(" "));
        }

}catch(IOException ie) {ie.printStackTrace();}

for(String[] pkt : pkts) {
    // process your hex string array 
}
```